# Get Google Analytics data with c# - where is this key?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, google-api, google-analytics-api

I want to get Google Analytic Data using c#. I would like to get visit count, Facebook's referral count and etc.

I have seen many sites about Google APIs, but they use key and I don't know how can I get this key.:

```
dataFeedUrl = "https://www.google.com/analytics/feeds/data" + gkey;
```

how can i do it?

Comment: I think you should look at the Google .net client library for this.  http://www.daimto.com/googleanalytics-authentication-csharp/

Comment: thanks @DaImTo, but i dont know how can i get  `keyFilePath = @"c:\file.p12"`.

Comment: Google Developers console

Comment: @DaImTo i dont have any project in Google Developers console . my project is hosted by github . my Google Developers console is empty.

Comment: Create a project with a service account credtial enabled the Google Analytics API.    You have the power :)

Comment: @DaImTo my boss has added my email in google analytic ,may be his google console is not empty?! and he can get me that key.  android apps can use Tracking ID.
i want to know that can i use Tracking ID instead of using the key from console?

Comment: Nope Google Developer console is where you can get the server account credtial add its email address in Google Analytics.   Its two different things.

Comment: Thanks @DaImTo. android apps can use Tracking ID. i want to know that can i use Tracking ID instead of using the key from console or not?

Comment: Are you sending data to Google Analytics or requesting data from Google Analytics? Tracking id is for sending data to Google Analytics.    Key is for requesting data from Google Analytics.    Fix your questions and make it clear what you are doing please.

Comment: @DaImTo In android app we send data and in web app we want to get data. Thanks, i didn't know that :)